# How to download Source code from Android Google Source With Gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

How to download the android project from android.googlesourece.com with the Gradle file!! I want to download the **DeskClock app**

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/tags/android-r-preview-2

but the project does not contain the Gradle file, also I did go through the [official documentation](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#getting-the-files) but I don't really understand well. is there a tutorial guys, can you guys guide me how to get the files with Gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These apps are part of AOSP build tree. There are **no Gradle files** for them. The information on how it is build, what its dependencies are is inside Android.mk (or Android.bp for newer versions) .

To build a such app, you'll have to download the whole AOSP tree, setup the environment, and then you can build a single module using `mmm packages/apps/DeskClock`.

You could always try to import it in Android Studio, and see if that works.
Apps in the AOSP tree often use non standard SDKs ( methods and classes that aren't part of official SDK that you get when developing Android apps).

It's generally difficult to build them out-of-tree like this. This might be of help for some references https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api.